# How to validate a more than one element in form like Name, City, and State by one function in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to make one common function in javascript for validation of my fields like name,city and state.
which can be also applicable for all three fields 
1) Name
2) City
3) State

Here is the code of html

```
<form name="addcust" method="POST" action="insrtCustomer.php" id="form1">
<table>
    <tr>
            <td>Customer Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><label id="message"></label></td>
            <td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="city" maxlength="25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>State</td><td><input type="text" name="state" maxlength="25"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make one function which i can use it for real time validation and can be applicable for more than one form.
As all you guys know that all forms in website has different name. So how it can be used, Please give your ideas here to do this and you all knows this can be usefull for other guys aso. So please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this and customize accordingly | **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ackMC/)**

Just you have to pass the form (this) in validate function and it will check for all text boxes for empty, you can modify it according to your use

```
<form name="addcust" method="POST" action="insrtCustomer.php" id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
<table>
    <tr>
            <td>Customer Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><label id="message"></label></td>
            <td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="city" maxlength="25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>State</td><td><input type="text" name="state" maxlength="25"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </form>
```

Javascript

```
function validate(dis)
{
    var ele = dis.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
         if(ele[i].getAttribute("type") == "text")
         {
                if(ele[i].value == "")
                {
                    alert(ele[i].getAttribute('name')+" is required feild");
                    ele[i].focus();
                    return false;
                }
         }

        // you can check for radio and checkboxes
        //eg :  if(ele[i].getAttribute("type") == "radio")
        // {
                // Your code here     
        // }
    }

 return true; // to prevent from form submission use false
}
```

**If you want to check for special characters**

```
function validate(dis)
{
    var filter = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    var ele = dis.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
         if(ele[i].getAttribute("type") == "text")
         {
                if(ele[i].value == "")
                {
                    alert(ele[i].getAttribute('name')+" is required feild");
                    ele[i].focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(!filter.test(ele[i].value))
                {
                    alert(ele[i].getAttribute('name')+" requires letters and numbers only");
                    ele[i].focus();
                    return false;
                }else;
         }

        // you can check for radio and checkboxes
        //eg :  if(ele[i].getAttribute("type") == "radio")
        // {
                // Your code here     
        // }
    }

 return true; // to prevent from form submission use false
}
```

Comment: This only for empty fields. But in real time validation it should be for blank, Special character also. so it can be possible to implement all these by your method

Comment: @SanjayRathod Ofcourse yes. i have checked for empty fields, you check for special chars too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example [JQuery Validation](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2)

Comment: Hi Prateek. Please avoid putting just plain links as answers to questions. At the very least, you should include code examples and a summary of the article you're linking to.

Comment: Please tell me how to use this?

Comment: Hello Sanjay Rathod i have one more example to show you and i think this will help you. Check this link. you need more help i will explain you. [Click here](http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/index.html)

Comment: @ahren thanx man. This help me lot for giving better answer. Next time i will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Include your jquery validation file in html page after jquery file

```
     $('#yourFormId').validate({
              rules:{
               name: {
                    required: true
                },
                city: {
                    required:true
                },
               state: {
                    required:true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name:{
                    required: 'required msg' 
                },
  city:{
                    required: 'required msg' 
                },  state:{
                    required: 'required msg' 
                }

            },
            submitHandler: function(form){

            }
        });
```

hope this will work...

Comment: This only for empty fields. But in real time validation it should be for blank, Special character also. so it can be possible to implement all these by your method

Comment: yes you can do all type of stuff... once you go through with jquery validation you can add more validation according to your needs.